# find documents with empty field / Attachment.Content in elastic search using Nest + C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to search for documents with an empty field. These attempts do not work:

```
var searchResult1 = client.Search<Doc>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
        .Field(f => f.Attachment.Content)
        .Query("")
        )
    )
);

var searchResult2 = client.Search<Doc>(x => x
    .Query(query => query
        .Term(term => term
        .Field(new Field("Attachment.Content"))
        .Value("")
        )
    )
);
```

Please note that Attachment is of type Nest.Attachment.

Answer (score 2):

did you already try [`Verbatim()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.x/verbatim-and-strict-query-usage.html)

```
var searchResult2 = client.Search<Doc>(x => x
.Query(query => query
    .Term(t => t.Verbatim()
    .Field(f => f.x)
    .Value("")
    )
)
);
```

Comment: Yes thanks (albeit different probably wrong attempt). This query returns no documents but I am sure that there are docs in my ES instance where content of field x.y is empty

Comment: @cs0815 this won't check for `null`, only for empty string - you're sure these values aren't `null`?

Comment: Actually I simplified my post I actually use Attachment.Content not x.y - where Attachment is Nest.Attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add up to [@fubo's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60814487/6682254). Make sure you index the field as `Keyword` **THEN** do a query search on term **otherwise** you will end up with no documents returned. (just as @cs0815, the author of the question, replied to the linked answer)

```
        private void EnsureIndexExitstance()
        {
            var indexExists = _elasticClient.Indices.Exists(indexName);

            if (!indexExists.Exists)
            {
                _elasticClient.Indices.Create(
                    indexName, 
                    c => c.Map<Document>(mm =>
                        mm.Properties(p =>
                            p.Keyword(k =>
                                k.Name("fieldName")))));
            }
        }
```